# What's the word for "been fighting for years"?

Tags: adjectives, adjective-phrases

I want to shorten the following sentence by making an adjective out of the phrase "parties that have been fighting for many years now":

*"The initiative aims at building trust among the parties that have been fighting for many years now."*

I thought about adding "long-warring" parties, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

*"The initiative aims at building trust among the **long-warring** parties."*

I'm translating a text and there's a specific number of words I can't exceed.

Comment: longtime combatants

Comment: Please consider waiting 24 hours before accepting an answer, even if you get a good one right away. You might get a better one if you give people in every time zone a chance to answer! For more info, see [this](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/6700).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Long-warring** is excellent!

Contemporary English seldom uses **war** as a verb, but the present participle **warring** is conventional. **Long-warring** is a very clear, concise way to communicate this idea. And you are right to include the hyphen.

Here's an example from a [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=q_CMTLzX7ZcC&pg=PA1&dq=%22long-warring%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDp42xqr_NAhXLMx4KHdKOAegQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=%22long-warring%22&f=false) written in 1994:

> In enacting the Omnibus Budget Reconciliation Act of 1990 (OBRA), the **long-warring branches** [of the U.S. government] looked ahead to a period of budget tranquility and rapidly declining deficits.

Notice that this example, which is fairly typical, uses **long-warring** metaphorically: not to describe a literal war, but to describe a long-running disagreement between different branches of government. The metaphor extends to using the word **tranquility** to describe the expected peace now that the "war" is concluded.

For more examples, see [Google Books](https://www.google.com/#q=%22long-warring%22&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1980%2Ccd_max%3A&tbm=bks) (which is a great source of information for this kind of question).

Answer (score 1):

*Feuding* is the word. See *[feud](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/feud)* (Oxford dictionary).

Comment: This might be a better choice than "long-warring", depending on the meaning that the OP wants to convey. (It might even count as one fewer word, depending on how they count hyphens.) Could you add some information about the difference in meaning and emphasis?